# Old Windows XP install stuck in loop. Cant finish install

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

A while ago I had a virus problem that really messed up my OS.  I tried to reinstall, and that did not work. I then spent another $100 on a new disc which did not work either and would not accept the key.

I gave up after that. A while has gone by and now I have a CD for Windows XP S3 corporate and student, which supposedly does not need a key or has one built in since it is multi-user.

That wont install. It is stuck on the old install.

Can you help me get the computer out of the old install so I can start over?

I have Puppy Linux on a disc, which allows me access to the inner works and files, but no other access.

Comment: There are many possibilities that could be causing this problem, try to remove some pieces of hardware that may be causing a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run a clean install. About.com has a walk-through titled: [How to Clean Install Windows XP](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxpclean1.htm) which should guide you through doing this.

If you continue to experience issues with the installation, the issue is likely hardware related.

PS I would consider upgrading, Windows XP is nearly out of support meaning within a year you will no longer get security updates; you will be severely vulnerable to attacks.